# Old SSL certificate still being served after renewing it

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

A few weeks ago I installed a new ssl certificate to replace an expiring one. The file name for the .crt and .key remained the same. Only the contents changed.

Now when I go to my site it says the the certificate has expired and I see that it is using the old certificate chain. I can confirm the contents of the crt and key are the updated ones.

Output of `gitlab-ctl status`

```
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 30354) 18091s; run: log: (pid 15271) 21131317s
run: logrotate: (pid 7332) 91s; run: log: (pid 30308) 21128931s
run: mailroom: (pid 30436) 18060s; run: log: (pid 15266) 21131317s
run: nginx: (pid 3586) 1761s; down: log: 0s, normally up, want up
run: postgresql: (pid 30446) 18059s; run: log: (pid 10566) 13738330s
run: redis: (pid 30448) 18059s; run: log: (pid 10696) 13738292s
run: sidekiq: (pid 30463) 18057s; run: log: (pid 15264) 21131317s
run: unicorn: (pid 30487) 18053s; run: log: (pid 15267) 21131317s
```

Output of `gitlab-ctl tail nginx`

```
2016/11/28 21:26:20 [crit] 6852#0: *13180076 SSL_shutdown() failed (SSL: error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init) while SSL handshaking, client: 55.108.238.72, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2016/11/28 21:26:23 [crit] 6852#0: *13180077 SSL_shutdown() failed (SSL: error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init) while SSL handshaking, client: 55.108.238.72, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Those critical messages happen every 3 seconds.

I've restarted the nginx process but it did nothing. I've also ran gitlab-ctl reconfigure but to no avail. My `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file has not changed. It still has the nginx ssl path

```
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/pki/tls/certs/sitename.com.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/pki/tls/private/sitename.com.key"
```

And it also has the external_url

```
external_url 'https://sitename.com/'
```

Comment: Is it possible that someone else re-certed it? Check the dates with your provider, and compare them with what is showing on your website. Good ole IE does a good job of showing you your cert info.

Comment: I contacted my certificate provider and confirmed all the information was correct

Comment: did you get a fix for this? my nginx on debian is doing the same

Answer (score 1):

Certificates are loaded when the webserver starts, so you need to reload/restart when updating them.

Comment: My post mentions that I've restarted the nginx process

Comment: Do you use a reverse proxy, or do you directly expose the gitlab nginx server?

Comment: No reverse proxy. It is direct

Comment: You may test your ssl settings with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ if your gitlab is exposed, to be sure that ngnix doesn't load your certificate, then, perform a full stop of gitlab, then start it again.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx will check for files ending in .conf in the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory for additional configuration. So check if you have created some file called ssl.conf and have configured the new SSL certificate in it.

Please run the following command to check the certificate validation:

```
openssl x509 -inform pem -in cerfile.cer -noout -text
```